# linux OS return value

Tags: linux, return-value, system-error

When Berkeley db updates some items using `db.put()`, it return **28**, and I go through the doc of bdb, find out that if return value > 0, it's a **system error**, not from bdb per se.

But where can I find out what this system error (exit code **28**) mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the file `errno.h` on your machine (there are usually several files, so follow the `#include` trail)

```
    #define ENOSPC          28      /* No space left on device */
```